# Develop Jenkinsfile using IntelliJ/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm searching for an easiest way to define some IDE so users could develop their Jenkinsfiles just as if they are developing in java.
Using IntelliJ, I've already added `*.gdsl` file with a content and installed a *jenkins-control-plugin*. But still, I don't understand how my current groovy project exposed to my Jenkins server and some particular job within it?

All I want, users could use autocompletion during their script development. Currently, here: `currentBuild.displayName = verBuild;` I get an error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'displayName'` and there is no autocompletion for `currentBuild`. How can I import specific jenkins job to the project within the IDE?

Comment: this might help (helped me)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796757/jenkinsfile-syntax-highlighting-in-java-project-using-intellij-idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkinsfile syntax highlighting in Java project using Intellij Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796757/jenkinsfile-syntax-highlighting-in-java-project-using-intellij-idea)

Comment: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jenkins-editor