# How to format Jenkinsfile locally?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, code-formatting

I want to format Jenkinsfile locally and understand if they are any formatting issues. I use sublime editor for editing. Is there a better editor which can also suggest me any formatting errors? I do not want to use any online formatting tools.

Comment: You can use Visual Studio Code with the Jenkins Pipeline Linter Connector plugin to format as well as [validate Jenkinsfile locally from within VS Code](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/11/07/Validate-Jenkinsfile/).

Comment: I tried this out and very good with the linting, I however cannot see how to use it to format the jenkinsfile

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ can be configured to parse Jenkinsfile as a regular Groovy file, as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796757/jenkinsfile-syntax-highlighting-in-java-project-using-intellij-idea) or [this article](http://vgaidarji.me/blog/2018/07/30/working-with-jenkinsfile-in-intellij-idea/). This allows to use standard Groovy formatting and syntax check.

However, you might want to consider using [Replay Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#replay) functionality in your Jenkins instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use VSCode and a Jenkinsfile. In order to format it, I use a popular Groovy code formatter extension, but first I must rename the Jenkinsfile to Jenkinsfile.groovy. I reformat it, then save it back to the original filename (without the .groovy extension).