# Intellij jenkins pipeline script syntax highlight / autocomplete

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, jenkins-groovy

I have a file "Jenkinsfile" in a java project, and Intellij-idea 2023.1.4 will automagically do syntax highlighting and even some basic code completion for me (though it doesn't make use of any .gdsl file I have). But ONLY with that filename.

**How do I get this behavior with some other filename, and get intellij to use the .gdsl files from jenkins to get code completion?**

I'm working on a project with multiple pipelines, all named differently with the .pipeline extension.

What I tried, by order of desperation:

- Looked up Intellij's help page, no mention of Jenkins at all.
- Found this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796757/jenkinsfile-syntax-highlighting-in-java-project-using-intellij-idea) , the solution didn't work for me.
- Found this [blog post](https://st-g.de/2016/08/jenkins-pipeline-autocompletion-in-intellij) , but it didn't work for me: I retrieved the .gdsl file from Jenkins and made sure to define the folder with .gdsl files as a source file, but every single method into the .gdsl file gets the error "No candidates found for method call method". I also added the .pipeline to the groovy file association, and it barely makes a difference: I get countless error like "No candidates found for method call node.".
- Tried to use some other filename without extension.
- Tried to use filenames that include "Jenkinsfile" at the beginning.

Nothing works. Am I doing something wrong? Did I miss something?

And again, it has nothing to do with the content of my pipeline scripts themselves, as everything works perfectly when their content is copy-pasted into the file named "Jenkinsfile".

Comment: Have you tried to add `*.gdsl` pattern to Jenkins file type in `Settings > Editor > File types`?

Comment: There is no Jenkins file type, and I did try with the groovy file type, not success.

Comment: I have `IntelliJ Groovy DSL configuration` file type there that is associated with `*.gdsl` file name pattern so there is some highlighting out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Intellij support:

> "The completion, highlighting, and other features for the Jenkinsfile
> are provided by the Groovy TextMate bundle functionality.
> Unfortunately, there is no option for now to specify another custom
> file type to be recognized the same way as Jenkinsfile.
>
> We have several feature requests regarding the problem in our
> YouTrack, for example, [this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-216484) I'd recommend you upvote it to show
> your interest"

So, I guess I am currently out of luck, this feature simply doesn't exist in Intellij IDEA at this point in time. I'll just edit my jenkins pipeline scripts, within the file "Jenkinsfile" for now.